# How to make popup view work

Tags: swift, popup

Newb question, so please bear with me.

In my `DetailViewController.swift` file, I have the following code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var popupView: UIView!

@IBAction func showPopUp(_ sender: Any) {
    let popoverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbPopUpID") as! PopupViewController
    self.addChildViewController(popoverVC)
    popoverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(popoverVC.view)
    popoverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

When I click on the showPopup button in my Detail View, the app crashes and points red line at `AppDelegate.swift` in the class:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
```

with the red `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`

Other things I have done:

1.) In the Detail view in `Main.storyboard`, I have added a `UIView` into the `ViewController`.  This is my popup. In the tutorial, it said to add a "UI view controller".  Could this be a typo? Can a View Controller hold another View Controller inside??  I'm guessing he meant to add a `UIView` that will serve as a popup window.  Agree?

2.) I have a class named `PopupViewController` which is a `UIViewController`.

Thanks so much for your patience.

Comment: Hi there, I am referencing this tutorial: http://www.seemuapps.com/how-to-make-a-pop-up-view

Comment: Drag a `UIViewController` onto the storyboard, set its class to `PopUpViewController` and add a red `UIView` to this. Make sure to set the identifier of this view controller to be "sbPopUpID". If you havent set the identifier that might be the problem.

Comment: Hi Pranav, thanks for your comments, but still same problem.  Any ideas?  Thanks again.

Comment: Another thing, why do `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` from your `AppDelegate` declaration? When you set breakpoints in `showPopUp` which line causes the error?

Comment: It's stopping here:  let popupView = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbPopUpID") as! PopupViewController

Comment: Delete `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` from your `AppDelegate` declaration.

Comment: I have created a new project and followed step by step but still no luck.